# How can I plot a 2D matrix with this style?

Tags: plotting, matrix

It is possible to plot the matrix like in the image. I'm using

```
ListPointPlot3D[Abs[amn], PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
```

Where amn is the 2D matrix but the result is not near to the image

```
    amn = {{-5.75339*10^-17 - 7.01058*10^-17 I, 
      0.00200623 + 0.00484347 I, -0.00897283 - 0.00897283 I, 
      0.020567 + 0.00851913 I, -0.0274853 - 9.22671*10^-17 I, 
      0.020567 - 0.00851913 I, -0.00897283 + 0.00897283 I, 
      0.00200623 - 0.00484347 I, -5.75339*10^-17 - 
       7.01058*10^-17 I}, {-0.00407975 - 1.51374*10^-16 I, 
      0.00318289 - 0.00592012 I, 
      0.00209445 + 0.0139195 I, -0.0182747 - 0.0180699 I, 
      0.0331421 - 1.57257*10^-16 I, -0.0182747 + 0.0180699 I, 
      0.00209445 - 0.0139195 I, 
      0.00318289 + 0.00592012 I, -0.00407975 - 
       1.51374*10^-16 I}, {0.00592459 - 1.37346*10^-16 I, -0.00710625 + 
       0.00468769 I, 0.00900641 - 0.0155891 I, 
      0.00893125 + 0.0378717 I, -0.0646945 - 5.77448*10^-17 I, 
      0.00893125 - 0.0378717 I, 
      0.00900641 + 0.0155891 I, -0.00710625 - 0.00468769 I, 
      0.00592459 - 1.37346*10^-16 I}, {0.0290561 + 
       7.6544*10^-17 I, -0.00623189 - 0.0356728 I, -0.0573817 + 
       0.034597 I, 0.111297 - 0.00957322 I, 0.323006 + 3.09492*10^-17 I, 
      0.111297 + 0.00957322 I, -0.0573817 - 0.034597 I, -0.00623189 + 
       0.0356728 I, 
      0.0290561 + 7.6544*10^-17 I}, {7.97973*10^-17 - 1.03917*10^-17 I, 
      0.00362693 + 0.00875619 I, 
      0.0211843 + 0.0211843 I, -0.0976489 - 0.0404475 I, 
      0.570093 + 2.32563*10^-18 I, -0.0976489 + 0.0404475 I, 
      0.0211843 - 0.0211843 I, 0.00362693 - 0.00875619 I, 
      7.97973*10^-17 - 1.03917*10^-17 I}, {-0.0290561 - 
       1.42283*10^-17 I, -0.0208179 - 0.0296311 I, 0.034597 - 0.0573817 I,
       0.0719297 + 0.0854683 I, 0.323006 + 4.23599*10^-17 I, 
      0.0719297 - 0.0854683 I, 
      0.034597 + 0.0573817 I, -0.0208179 + 0.0296311 I, -0.0290561 - 
       1.42283*10^-17 I}, {-0.00592459 + 1.64616*10^-18 I, 
      0.00833958 - 0.00171018 I, -0.0155891 + 0.00900641 I, 
      0.0330947 - 0.020464 I, -0.0646945 - 5.90368*10^-17 I, 
      0.0330947 + 0.020464 I, -0.0155891 - 0.00900641 I, 
      0.00833958 + 0.00171018 I, -0.00592459 + 
       1.64616*10^-18 I}, {0.00407975 - 3.94513*10^-17 I, -0.0064368 - 
       0.00193552 I, 0.0139195 + 0.00209445 I, -0.0256995 - 0.00014478 I, 
      0.0331421 - 6.04677*10^-18 I, -0.0256995 + 0.00014478 I, 
      0.0139195 - 0.00209445 I, -0.0064368 + 0.00193552 I, 
      0.00407975 - 3.94513*10^-17 I}, {-5.75339*10^-17 - 7.01058*10^-17 I,
       0.00200623 + 0.00484347 I, -0.00897283 - 0.00897283 I, 
      0.020567 + 0.00851913 I, -0.0274853 - 9.22671*10^-17 I, 
      0.020567 - 0.00851913 I, -0.00897283 + 0.00897283 I, 
      0.00200623 - 0.00484347 I, -5.75339*10^-17 - 7.01058*10^-17 I}}
```

The values are complex numbers basically, can be use any complex values, the requirement is a complex 2d matrix

[image]

Comment: try `ListPlot3D` instead of `ListPointPlot3D`?

Comment: The problem is that I need that kind of pyramidal shape over the matrix entry, ListPlot3d produces a continuous surface

Answer (score 1):

To do this you might have to add extra values to your matrix, essentially to "pin down" the values of `ListPlot3D` to 0 between your "actual" matrix values. We can do that as follows:

```
mRiffle0[m_?MatrixQ] := 
 Riffle[Riffle[#, 0, {1, -1, 2}] & /@ 
         m, {ConstantArray[0, 1 + 2*Dimensions[m][[2]]]}, {1, -1, 2}]

ListPlot3D[mRiffle0[Abs[amn]], PlotRange -> Full, Mesh -> Full, DataRange -> {{-4.5, 4.5}, {-4.5, 4.5}}]
```

(I'm not sure if I got the `DataRange` quite right, but you can play with it if you want. You can also change `PlotStyle`, `MeshStyle`, and `Lighting` to make it even closer!)
[image: The 3D plot produced by the above code.]

Answer (score 1):

At first we use `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to draw the piecewise function.

```
data = Abs[amn];
fig = ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
   Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> None];
```

[image]

Then we replace all the space rectangles to pyramids by

```
pts = {{0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}};
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.8], Polygon[pts]}, {FaceForm[White], 
   EdgeForm[Black], Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
   Pyramid[Append[ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 0}]@pts, Mean[pts]]]}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

That is

```
Normal[fig] /. 
 Polygon[a___] :> {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
   Pyramid[Append[ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 0}]@First@Polygon[a], 
     Mean[First@Polygon[a]]]]}
```

[image]